# Keyboard navigation on badges page is broken

Tags: bug, keyboard-shortcuts

The keyboard navigation using the keyboard-shortcuts is broken on the badges page.

When using Key <kbd>U</kbd> to select the first badge, it always selects the 2. section from left in the footer. See screenshot below.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Enable Keyboard shortcuts in profile
2. Go to [home](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)
3. Type <kbd>G</kbd>
4. Type <kbd>B</kbd> (go to Badges)
5. Type <kbd>U</kbd> (select first badge) -> footer element selected

[image]

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why only for Q´s and A´s? On the User and Tag page the navigation is working fine. So it should also work for badges. Also are these keys listed in the help menu.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the user and tag pages, actually. :-) Clearly, I am mistaken.

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox Aurora 33.02a. Thanks for teaching me that keyboard shortcuts exist!

Comment: @doppelgreener you should really subscribe to Nick's answers. :)

Comment: I can no longer reproduce this issue (the U option is not available on the Badges page).